# removing discrete closed intervals from boost::icl::interval_set

Tags: c++, boost, intervals

```
  boost::icl::interval_set<uint> test_set;
  test_set.insert(boost::icl::discrete_interval<uint>::closed(10u, 20u));
  test_set.insert(boost::icl::discrete_interval<uint>::closed(21u, 30u)); //should merge to single interval
  test_set.insert(boost::icl::discrete_interval<uint>::closed(15u, 25u)); //should not change
  test_set.erase(boost::icl::discrete_interval<uint>::closed(12u, 18u)); //should split in two intervals
  uint i1min = test_set.begin()->lower();
  uint i1max = test_set.begin()->upper();
  uint i2min = (++test_set.begin())->lower();
  uint i2max = (++test_set.begin())->upper();
  std::cout<<i1min<<"\n";
  std::cout<<i1max<<"\n";
  std::cout<<i2min<<"\n";
  std::cout<<i2max<<"\n";
```

since I am adding and subtracting closed intervals, I would expect the following output:

```
10
11
19
30
```

but instead I get:

```
10
12
18
30
```

why do the endpoints of the interval I am removing remain? Is this the expected behaviour with subtracting closed intervals or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subtracting one closed interval from another, in your case results in two half-open intervals. If you think about it, it is consistent with the behaviour of continuous intervals as well.

You can test this with the following code:

```
 std::cout << test_set.begin()->bounds() << "\n";
 std::cout << (++test_set.begin())->bounds() << "\n";
```

This outputs: `[)` and `(]` showing that the resulting intervals are half-open, meaning that `12` and `18` are not included in your interval set.

To get the first/last elements of the (possibly open) discrete interval, use the functions `first` and `last` (docs [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/function_reference/range.html)):

```
uint i1min = boost::icl::first(*test_set.begin());
uint i1max = boost::icl::last(*test_set.begin());
uint i2min = boost::icl::first(*(++test_set.begin()));
uint i2max = boost::icl::last(*(++test_set.begin()));
```

Comment: oh I see, this makes sense! in that case, is there a way to get the highest element of a discrete interval that is still part of the interval?